# Why does a strange line appear around my div when zooming out/in?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My code is quite simple:

```
<div class="mail-header-title">
    ${title}
</div>
<div class="mail-header-down-rounded-triangle">
   <img src="fill-1@3x.png"/>
</div>

 .mail-header-title {
            padding: 24px 50px 36px 50px;
            width: 591px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 42px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-stretch: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            line-height: 1.29;
            letter-spacing: normal;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .mail-header-content {
            padding: 13px 50px 16px 50px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-stretch: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            line-height: 1.56;
            letter-spacing: normal;
            color: #444560;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border: none !important;
        }

        .mail-header-down-rounded-triangle {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
            border: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
        }

        .mail-header-down-rounded-triangle img {
            height: 24px;
            width: 101px;
            /*content: url("fill-1@3x.png");*/
        }
```

The first div background is blue, and the second div contains this image below.
[image: image used in second div]

I'm sure I set div border as ***none***. 
When the page is rendered, everything looks ok. But when I zoom in/out, 
this blue line appears.
[image: unexpected result]

I'm not sure what happened, any idea about this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: try to set the top in css to a negative number so it goes a bit into it. it may seem a dirty trick but works for me. so in your css add `margin-top: 10px`

Comment: yeah, I think just like you do, and it really works, not sure why this happen.